# msix and multiple target frameworks not working

Tags: .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, msix

I have wpf project with multiple target frameworks

`<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.0;net48</TargetFrameworks>`

In vs2019 I created `Windows Application Packaging Project` (MSIX package) and add reference to my project.

But when I trying to build packaging project I get this error:

```
error MSB4057: The target "GetTargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker" does not exist in the project.
error MSB4057: The target "GetTargetPath" does not exist in the project.
error MSB4057: The target "GetDeployableContentReferenceOutputs" does not exist in the project.
```

When I use single target everything works fine

`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>`